# Argument exception in .Net Regular Expression

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to search text from one set of dashes to another and include all lines in between, but my regex is giving this error in visual studio

> parsing "^[-]{10,}*\n(?:.*\n)+?[-]{10,}" - Nested quantifier *.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex dash = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[-]{10,}*\n(?:.*\n)+?[-]{10,}");
```

Text looks like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX0 0000000000X00XXXXXXXXXXX00X00XXXX000000000 XXXXX000X0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX XXXX000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00000XX000X000X0000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXX00X0000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00X00X00X00 00XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX00000000XXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX0000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX00000X0 000XXX000X000X0 000XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX0X0XXXXXXXXXXX00000X0XX00000XX0 0000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT:  I think I missed a period before the *\n - this caused the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `{10,}*`, which are two quantifiers: `{10,}` and `*` side by side. This causes that error to show.

Comment: yes this is correct, I realized this after posting :)

Comment: @erotavlas - As you already thought, this could have been a missed `.` before the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex to match the lines which are located in between the dashes.

```
(?<=^[-]{10,}.*?\n)(?:.*\n)+?(?=[-]{10,})
```

Comment: this produced no match

Comment: try `(?<=-+).*(?=-+)` with `s` and `g` modifier.